# Data structure for iterating over subsets of a collection

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a general question about algorithims/data structures.
There is no specific programming language.

I'm working with arrays of boolean values.
The size of the arrays is always 50.

I want to have a collections of these arrays.

I will need to iterate over my collection multiple times.

In order to increase performance, I would like to limit each iteration to a subset of the collection. Rather than the whole collection.

For instance: to iterate only over the arrays that have FALSE in the 4th and 13th position

I will NOT need to search for TRUE values. Only for FALSE values in certain positions of the array.

Note that the possible subsets can share elements without one being included in the other.

Is there any kind of data structure that could help me?

Comment: "FALSE in the 4th and 13th position" - are there fixed sets of possible positions you need to check or should one essentially be able to input any positions during runtime to get the matching arrays? That would change the problem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short piece on this in Knuth Volume III "Sorting and Searching" section 6.5. There are a few simple schemes laid out there with somewhat limited effectiveness, which suggests to me that there are no magic answers to this hard problem of searching multi-dimensional spaces.

One approach described here (with parameters adjusted for your problem) is to divide your 50 bits into 5 10-bit chunks, and create 5 hash tables, each mapping a value for one of those 10-bit chunks to a list of all the records which have that value in the given position. Given values for particular bit positions, choose whichever one of the 10-bit chunks contains the most known bits, and use this to only check 512 or 256 or 128 of the 1024 lists in the table for that chunk, depending on whether you know 1, 2, or 3 of the bit positions in that chunk.